# How to make a custom control inherit his style from his parent?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, coding-style, inheritance

I have a custom combobox (*`MyComboBox`*) defined in my code (by making a class inherit from `ComboBox`.
There is no XAML file associated, it's only to add some behavior.

It works as intended, however, the style which is applied to the standard `ComboBox` isn't applied to `MyComboBox`.

How can I make my custom combobox inherit its default style from `ComboBox` ?  I tried with

```
DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ComboBox);
```

in the constructor, but it didn't change anything.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer in this thread : http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/218761/522162.aspx#522162

Which is basically to modify the constructor like this :

```
public MyComboBox()
{
    try
    {
        foreach (ResourceDictionary res in App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries)
        {
            if (res[typeof(ComboBox)] is Style)
            {
                this.Style = (Style)res[typeof(ComboBox)];
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```